# Laravel, Eloquent: Relationships. Запись двух сущностей в 1 строку

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, связи

Есть 3 сущности. Article, User и Category.

Article

```
class Article extends Model{
  public function user()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

 public function category()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

User

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
public function articles()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
  }
```

Category

```
class Category extends Model{
public function articles()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
  }
}
```

Чтобы сохранить в бд пользователя, который создал статью, в контроллере я использую следующий код:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
      $user = Auth::user();
      $article = new Article(['name' => 'test']);

      //сохраняю запись
      $user->articles()->save($article);
}
```

}

Но мне так же нужно в таблицу со статьями сохранить категорию статьи.
Категорию статьи я получаю в контроллере:

```
$category = Category::find(2);
```

Но каким образом мне сохранить две эти сущности($user и $category) внутрь $article. Т.е. нужно чтобы в таблице articles были 2 ячейки - user_id и category_id.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: не пойму чем тебя не устраивает вариант `$article = Article::create( ['name'=>'test', 'catalog' =>$catalog_id, 'user_id'=>auth()->user()->id])`

Comment: Потому что вручную прописываются поля category_id и user_id. Я раньше работал c symfony doctrine orm, и там работы как таковой с полями бд вообще не было, только с сущностями. Если в laravel такого нельзя сделать, тогда придется вручную прописывать